# Alert not working with React Hooks & Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, alerts

I'm building a project where people can nominate movies that are their favorites.  I am also attempting
to have an alert show up when a submit button is clicked to submit all nominations.

````
return (

        <React.Fragment>

            <div id="nomination-div">

                Your Nominations

                {generateNominationCards()}

                <Button
                    variant="primary" onClick={() => submitNominations()}>
                    Submit Nominations
                </Button>

            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    );
    ```

Here is the code I have for my ```submitNominations()``` button.
````

```
function submitNominations(){

    return(
        <Alert variant="success">
        <Alert.Heading>Hey, nice to see you</Alert.Heading>
        <p>
            Aww yeah, you successfully read this important alert message. This example
            text is going to run a bit longer so that you can see how spacing within an
            alert works with this kind of content.
        </p>
        <hr />
        <p className="mb-0">
            Whenever you need to, be sure to use margin utilities to keep things nice
            and tidy.
        </p>
        </Alert>
    )
}
```

```
I'm using this link as my guide: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts/

I have <Alerts> defined in a separate file with the rest of my react-bootstrap components like so 

    const Jumbotron = ReactBootstrap.Jumbotron;
    const Badge = ReactBootstrap.Badge;
    const Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;
    const Carousel = ReactBootstrap.Carousel;


Nothing is currently showing up or happening for me at all.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not something like an alert shows in React will generally be *state-driven*, so in this case you might have a `showAlert` boolean state value and set that to `true` when you want to show the alert. Then, just conditionally render the Alert content in your returned JSX. See below for an example of how this might work.

```js
function MyComponent() {
    const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);

    const submitNominations = () => {
        setShowAlert(true);
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {showAlert && (
                <Alert variant="success">
                    <Alert.Heading>Hey, nice to see you</Alert.Heading>
                    <p>
                        Aww yeah, you successfully read this important alert message. This example text is going to run a bit longer so that you can see how spacing within an alert works with this kind of content.
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <p className="mb-0">
                        Whenever you need to, be sure to use margin utilities to keep things nice and tidy.
                    </p>
                </Alert>
            )}
            <div id="nomination-div">
                Your Nominations
                {generateNominationCards()}
                <Button
                    variant="primary" onClick={() => submitNominations()}>
                    Submit Nominations
                </Button>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```